# Cordova Media won't play mp3 from www

Tags: android, cordova

I have found lots of potential resolutions to this issue on StackOverflow but nothing seems to be resolving it for me. I am trying to play an mp3 file within my Cordova (3.5) app using `org.apache.cordova.media@0.2.10`

```
var sound = new Media('audio/el/hello.mp3');
sound.play()
```

But it just won't play and I get the following error in LogCat

```
MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648)
```

I have tried serving the folder locally and the following works pointing at the same file

```
var sound = new Media('http://10.0.2.2:9999/www/audio/el/hello.mp3');
sound.play()
```

Which suggests that it isn't because the file has an encoding problem.

I wasn't able to use the latest version of the `media` plugin because the `deviceready` event never fires.

**Update**: I've just tried unzipping the files to persistent storage and playing them from there and I get the same error.

**Update**: Stepping through the `AudioPlayer.java` source it seems that the `www` directory is not part of the assets because the following call throws a `FileNotFoundException` where `f == "www/el/hello.mp3"`

```
fd = this.handler.cordova.getActivity().getAssets().openFd(f);
```

However If I place the files directly in the `assets` folder then it works.

Answer (score 7):

Path of media file incorrect. You must get path correctly:

```
var getPathMedia = function () {
var path = window.location.pathname;
var phoneGapPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
// Return path at www folder
return 'file://' + phoneGapPath;
};
var media = new Media(getPathMedia() + 'media/message.mp3');
media.play();
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but the actual file isn't being picked up correctly.

Answer (score 5):

On android, you only need to have the correct path for the `www` folder.

Android:

```
var media = new Media("/android_asset/www/audio/el/hello.mp3",
    successFunction,
    errorFunction
);
```

If your app is going to run on iOS as well, you need to add the `/android_asset/www/` dynamically as iOS does not need it.

iOS:

```
var media = new Media("audio/el/hello.mp3",
    successFunction,
    errorFunction
);
```

Comment: I tried that and for some reason the /www folder cannot be accessed but the /android__asset folder can

Comment: It needs to be /android_asset/www/whatever not /www or even ./www or ./whatever

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out for myself, but I figured I'd share.

What I needed to do is not get the location, but the current url to the page I was on.  From that I could construct a url to the asset I wanted to play.

```
var path = window.location.href;
var phoneGapPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var media = new Media(phoneGapPath + 'media/message.mp3');
media.play();
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am using this plugin with ionic capacitor. I had to use a different filepath, when playing audiofiles that are located in assets folder. Additionally I had to call the release function after the
onSuccess-event fired. When I called it after file.play(), the playback didn't work.

```
var audioPath = "/android_asset/public/assets/" + "audio.mp3"
const file: MediaObject = this.media.create(audioPath)
file.onSuccess.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Action is successful')
    file.release()
});
file.play();
```

If the audio file is not found, make sure to check that it is copied to the android project assets folder. If it is not there run "npx cap sync" and "npx cap copy".

Comment: what happen if you have your mp3 file in app folder (or any folder under root)?

Comment: That doesn't work. But I also switched to the plugin: [capacitor-community/native-audio](https://github.com/capacitor-community/native-audio) because it doesn't need record permissions. And I wasn't able to remove the permission for Android, even though it is not in my manifest.xml File.